# Postgresql - Fetch record based on previous record

Tags: postgresql

Am having table employee with columns (id,date,region,salary) and data looks like below

```
id date         region    salary
1  1-jan-2015   USA       8000
1  1-jan-2016   USA       8000
1  1-jan-2016   INDIA     67000
1  1-jan-2017   USA       9000
```

In above data, u can see salary details present for two different regions for the same date as  (USA-8000 and INDIA-67000)

I need to get the only value as USA-8000 for the year 2016 as the previous region (2015) is USA .

If the previous region is India then i need to fetch india record from 2016.

Kindly help.

Comment: previous alphabetically?.. id is same, date is same. Postgres moves rows phisically - there is no way to know which row was inserted before the other, unless you have some db structure for it (timestamp or sequential id or smth else)

Comment: When date is same, the record should picked based on previous region.

Comment: how previous? in alphabet? I don't see any rownumber. how should I order it?..

Comment: U can order using date 2015-USA .So if 2016 has 2 records then i wanna to get single record based on previous year region.I hope u understands

Comment: add another row `1  1-jan-2017   INDIA 2000` - which you want for 2017 then?..